# Ggplot size in shinyR apps

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I developed a shiny app that renders several plots using ggplot. However, the rendered plots are not taking the max width of the main panel and I can't figure it out how to adjust the size of ggplot to maximise its visualization.

The app can be visualized here: https://icra.shinyapps.io/nbs-list/

The code can be found here: https://github.com/icra/nbs_list/

(I didn't copy paste because it's 452 lines length).

Thank you.

Comment: Try using height and width arguments for [`renderPlot`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderPlot.html). Setting them to `"auto"` should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: I tried, but it changed the windows size where plot is rendered. Visually, it only changed the horitzontal location of the plot. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `ui`

```
             #if top NBS is selected
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.top_custom.includes('top_NBS')",
                                plotOutput("plot_top", height="700px")
               ),
               
               #if custom NBS is selected
               conditionalPanel(condition = "input.top_custom.includes('custom_NBS')",
                                plotOutput("plot_facet", height="700px")
               )
```

It works for me. With 700px, it gives the following output

[image: output1]

Regardless of the size, some of the blank space above the plot needs to be deleted. With 400px it gives the following ouput:

[image: output2]

Comment: I tried, using height, width and both and nothing changed in the plot size. Thank you!